# There should be possibility to filter "Help and Improved" reviews proposals by tags you are interested in

Tags: feature-request, review-queues, help-improvement, filtering

There is a very small chance that you would like to improve question you are not interested in. Currently "Help and Improved" proposes even questions were listed as "Ignored".

Alternatively: we have the skip button - that is good. But could you duplicate tags on the "stable" top of the screen (to avoid searching by eyes or even worst: scrolling)?

P.S. Skip is not a good solution. After 10 skips you got bored. Just reading  of unknown topics makes you tired very quickly.

UPDATED:

H&I queue is specific: all complex/unclear/ambiguous cases end up there - all clear, understandable, direct cases were solved early. But you can't escape this stage in any decision flow system. Just provide the tag filter as a last chance to show this post to the expert.

UPDATED:
It is even supposed by SO that reviewer should understand something on the topic, not only be able "to remove greetings".

[image]

Comment: "10 skips -> got bored -> close the tab" is the typical, and recommended way to deal with this queue.

Comment: Then why there is no award for 1000 skips?

Comment: @RomanPokrovskij Why is there no badge for 1000 skips? Probably because Skip doesn't improve the site. FWIW I did once [propose a WinterBash hat for Skipping](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/270418/168333).

Comment: I hope search index was improved.

Answer (score 3):

The reason HI is unusable is because the questions there are almost exclusively questions that can't be salvaged by *anyone* (or at least any reviewer), not because there's a lack of domain knowledge.  In fact, if you are making an edit to a question based strongly on your domain knowledge there's a very good chance that *your edit is inappropriate and you shouldn't be making it*.  Edits are there to improve the existing question, not change it into a different question, and as a result of that it's pretty rare to need much, if any, domain knowledge to make good edits.

What you need to make good edits is strong English and writing skills, good knowledge of SO's formatting system, and a good understanding of how the tagging system works.

Comment: This totally ignores "reading phase" of review. It should be interested to read it first, and second - domain knowledge makes reading/evaluating phase quicker.

Comment: @RomanPokrovskij The HI queue isn't there to help you find questions you'd be interested in.  There are mechanisms that exist for that, but HI isn't one of them.  It's a queue that exists to help you find posts that you can edit, and domain knowledge isn't a relevant factor in that.

Comment: Dialog like: "please, make reading phase more comfortable for reviewers" - "edit by yourself with full comfort". Ok.

Comment: @RomanPokrovskij And why aren't you comfortable editing the spelling of a Python post, or removing salutations from a Java question?

Comment: Because "Help and Improved" review track doesn't propose posts like you have just described.

Comment: @RomanPokrovskij That's it's job.  Of course, it's never done it's job since day 1, but that's just because Triage doesn't do it's job properly and people don't actually send improvable posts to HI.  It has nothing to do with the existence or lack of a tag filter.

Comment: I do not have other people for you.

Comment: Originally, H&I was also about teaching new users how the site works. Not just editing people's posts, but explaining to them _why_ you made the edit. So that the next time they post, they would understand the site a little better, improving their chance of getting help and points.

Comment: @S.L.Barth That's the first/late posts queue, not HI, and it still is that (well, maybe slightly broader, but the idea is to fix all of the problems with the post and help the author better understand how to interact with the site).

Comment: True - but originally H&I was broader. Completing a review there was hard work. Nowadays even the smallest edit will suffice there :-(

Comment: @S.L.Barth There were plans *before it ever existed in any form* for it to do more.  Even the original beta release of the queue had it being nothing more than a platform for edits.  Even in the original beta release even the smallest edit sufficed.  It's one of the reasons the queue was dead on arrival.  Well, that and the guidance given to Triage users being completely broken.

Comment: @S.L.Barth Oh, and of course even those other things that some people hoped HI would do that it never ended up being built to do still wouldn't require domain knowledge to do, so there'd be no reason to filter the posts by tag.

Comment: They force reviewers to read posts without a chance to answer, comment or vote and then: "*It is  dead on arrival*"...

Comment: @RomanPokrovskij None of the review queues allow you to answer, and several entirely effective queues don't allow you to vote or comment.  That's not what made the queue DOA.  If you're looking for a place to go to answer, comment, or vote on posts then *there are lots of places for you* (bother review queues and elsewhere), but HI just isn't one of them.  You seem to think that it's there to do something radically different than what it's *actually* there for.

Comment: "This is a specific queue"  "I do not want to see its specific it is just dead". Ok.

Comment: @RomanPokrovskij If you're going to quote people, actually quote them, rather than quoting things that they didn't actually say (or don't quote them at all, that works too).  It helps you get your point across better.

Comment: Correct me if I wrong: you want to discuss Triage, and not interested in real posts from H&I queue.

Comment: @RomanPokrovskij The queues are inexorably linked.  You often can't talk about one without talking about the other, as they both have such a significant impact on the other.  I've given you the answer to your question, which only really tangentially relates to Triage.  You brought up the fact that the queue often fails to present you with the types of posts it's supposed to.  The reason for that is Triage, not the existence or lack of a post filter.  Adding a filter would do nothing to change the fact that Triage is sending posts that don't require community editing.

Comment: Yes they are linked. H&I is the desk where all complex/unclear cases end up. There will be always such specific desk. And on this desk there should be filter: "give me something I can understand".  Alternatively we can try to  find other planet.

Comment: @RomanPokrovskij You don't need to go to another planet to design the queues better so that HI gets sent posts that can actually be improved.  The way to do that isn't to add tag filters, because there aren't going to be improvable posts in some tags and not others, and your ability to improve any given post has no relation to your expertise in the topics it involves (and instead on whether the reviewers of that post in Triage did their job right or not).  Giving you posts in tags you feel you can answer, but that aren't improvable, is just as useless as giving you such questions in other tags